# JS, Crear 90 números aleatorios entre 1 y 90, sin repetición

Tags: javascript

> En mi script estoy incluyendo los 0, pero ese no es el problema, yo lo que quiero es que no se repitan, crear 90 números entre 1 y 90 y que su secuencia sea aleatoria. Imagino que el problema esta dentro del while en la función secuencia. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano. ||El problema era en alea.splice que eliminaba lo que no debía ;) ||

```
<script>
    function crear90num() {
        var numeros = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 90; i++) {
            numeros[i] = i;
        }

        return numeros;
    }

    function crear0() {
        var tablero = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= 90; i++) {
            tablero[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    function secuencia() {
        var secuencia = [];
        var alea = crear90num();

        while (secuencia.length <= 90) {
               var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * alea.length);
            var num2 = alea[num];
            alea.splice(num, 1);
            secuencia.push(num2);
        }

        return secuencia;
    }


    function mostrar(resultado) {
        document.getElementById("a").value = resultado;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: entonces esta solucionado?

Comment: si llegaste a solucionar. escribí una respuesta a la solución y como como solucionado. Gracias